# During creating extension method with generics,Can not provide arguments when creating an instance of a variable type Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
    public static void MdiBroShow<TForm, T>(this Form form, T entity, DbContext db)
        where TForm : Form, new() where T : class, new()
    {
        if (form.MdiParent == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error");
        }
        TForm frm = new TForm(entity);   //error
        frm.MdiParent = form.MdiParent;
        frm.Show();
    }
```

I want to create extension metod to use during creation any form.This extension metod is in different project from I will use.Entity will be object of a class and I will send it in a form as generic.But I couldn't send it as a parameter.How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is a possible duplicate, but the other question has a *lot* of different answers.  And there's enough context to recommend a single, simple solution here.  In particular this code is creating a displaying a new form, so it's not a performance-critical method, and so the simplest solution is sufficient:

```
TForm frm = (TForm)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TForm), entity);
```